# Has anyone had any experience with first party cookies, setting a first party cookie for Safari's ITP policy

Tags: php, nginx, cookies, safari

I am trying to load an iframe across domains, in order to reuse a form submission that collates data into a single point.

I have managed to get most of the functionality and styling working cross domains, enabling CSP policies etc, but I am having issues with Safari and trying to set first-party cookies.

I have used some of the older techniques for setting first-party cookies with redirects, but for whatever reason, the cookies aren't set when I use the redirect to the embedded domain in order to set domains. I think the main issue with the redirect is that you need to have a user interaction as per the Webkit specifications.

I am trying to make this experience as seamless as possible for the user.

Any feedback appreciated, using PHP, NGINX and some JS, HTML & CSS.

I have access to the remote server that will be referenced in the iframe, but will also be liaising with the developer for the domain where the iframe will be embedding

Comment: Yeah, if the redirect trick still worked, the policy would be rather pointless - because then every I-track-you-over-dozens-of-websites advertiser would use it as well. // What info do you need to pass via cookie - just a session ID, or more?

Comment: Ye I understand the reason for changing it, I would like to pass session data for the current users session. I am using WooCommerce and loading an external sites product offering, and there is checkout process that can be completed via the iframe, but WooCommerce now stores the cart data via session cookies for the user

Comment: So from your WC site, an external site gets opened, and that again embeds your WC cart, so that the order process can be finished there, is that correct? Then the session cookie _is_ already set, and the problem is probably rather that it does not get send back by the browser in this scenario, because in the iframe your WC site is the 3rd party now. So you will need to pass the session ID in some other way - GET or POST. First it has to be transported from your WC to that external site, and that one then has to pass it into the iframe again.

Comment: But I suppose inside the iframe, you'd have keep passing it to the next page via GET/POST then, because the cookie will keep on getting blocked as a 3rd-party one.

Comment: Ye so thats the issue, the external site is being treated as a 3rd party cookie, which is correct, but I am not setting cookies for tracking purposes, Im setting cookies for their cart and session.

So I am trying to find a way to either pass the information across the iframe, so I have been using post message and catching the message, but it would be simpler if I could set a first party cookie and then request StorageAccess. I have managed to get this to work with a pop up window that notifies the user that a cookie is being sent, which gets a user interaction and sets the cookie.

Comment: But the browser can't determine, _what_ purpose you are using your cookies for. So the only choice the browser vendor has, is to either block 3rd-party cookies in general - or give up on trying to extend privacy protection in that regard altogether. (Yes, they could still give the user a choice on a case-by-case basis - but that will be too much bother for most people, so most would just opt to accept anything, and still end up "unprotected".)

Comment: Ye I agree, and the problem is vendors are constantly abusing updates meant to help the user, in order to track a user without consent